# password generator with conditoins (c#)

Tags: c++, if-statement, while-loop, passwords, generator

I am supposed to create a password generator in C++ with these conditions:

- 30 characters
- at least 1 lower case letter
- 6 capital letters
- at least 8 digits
- 2 to 5 special characters

So far I've only managed to create a random number generator for all characters and it's a bit difficult for me to include the conditions. Can anyone help me? Thank you in advance!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  srand(time(0));
  string pass;

  string data = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
              "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
              "0123456789"
              ";,:.+-*/%><=!~^&|[]{}()";
  for (int i=0; i<=30; i++) //30 characters
  {

  pass = pass + data[rand()% 100]; //random generator
  }

  cout << "Your password: " << pass;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `% 100` will go out-of-bounds of the string `data`.

Comment: pick 8 digits, pick 6 capital letters, pick 1 lower case letter, pick 2 special characters, append and shuffle those. Then add the missing characters randomly.

Comment: what help do you need specifically? Its hard to help when we do not know what prevents you from going further. I suggest you to pick one detail and try to write the code for it. If the code is ok fine, pick the next detail. If the code is not ok you have something to show that others can help with more easily

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/4165552